# Ubuntu: setting a workspace layout in i3

Tags: window-manager, i3, workspaces

how can I set a tabbed layout for a specific workspace, so only that workspace is tabbed, and other ones unchanged?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in a script and load it via your i3 config file:

```
i3-msg "workspace X; layout tabbed"
```

The [official documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#configuring) or [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3) are the best sources of information on configuration in my experience.